# Grid card layout not displaying correctly with 1 column

Tags: html, css, grid, card

I have an issue which I am trying to resolve now for while. I have created a landing page with a grid layout and it works perfectly fine with 4 (standard), 3 and 2 columns. However it gets distorted when minimising it to 1 column and I am just unable to figure out why. I have tried different settings in my CSS, but it wouldn't display the 1 column view properly.

[image]

Here is how it looks with 2 or more columns - perfectly fine and responsive:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul class="cards">
            <li class="cards_item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card_image"><img src="resources/black.png"></div>
                    <div class="card_content">
                        <h2 class="card_title">Some Text</h2>
                        <p class="card_text">This is some text.</p>
                        <div class="card-button">
                            <a href="https://tadat" target="_blank"><button class="btn-public" title="hello"><i
                                        class="fa-solid fa-globe" style="font-size:26px;"></i></button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="cards_item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card_image"><img src="resources/black.png"></div>
                    <div class="card_content">
                        <h2 class="card_title">Some more text</h2>
                        <p class="card_text">This is some text.
                        </p>
                        <div class="card-button">
                            <a href="https://tada" target="_blank"><button class="btn-public" title="hello"><i
                                        class="fa-solid fa-globe" style="font-size:26px;"></i></button></a>
                            <a href="https://tada" target="_blank"><button class="btn-legend" title="hello"><i
                                        class="fa-solid fa-bars-staggered" style="font-size:26px;"></i></button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: left;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.link {
    width: 100%;
}


.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.cards_item {
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 20rem) {
    .cards_item {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 35rem) {
    .cards_item {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 50rem) {
    .cards_item {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 60rem) {
    .cards_item {
        width: 25%;
    }
}

.card {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    /* box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card_content {
    padding: 1rem;
    /* background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #F2F2F2 40%, #d9ecff 100%); */
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card_title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    /* text-transform: capitalize; */
    margin: 0px;
}

.card_text {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to do two things:

### 1.

```css
.cards_item {
    /* display: flex; <== This item does not need to be a flex */
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

### 2.

```css
img {
    width: 100%; /* Use width instead of max-width */
    height: 150px: /* Use some fixed value here */
    object-fit: cover; /* Prevents stretching or squeezing the image  */ 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Hi Erno, thanks for the suggestions. However I still have the same issue. Now the image gets streched out but the cards with longer text are still bigger then the others. Only happens for 1 column view though still, 2 or more columns look fabulous.